# Mercurial how to achieve prod-test-dev

Tags: mercurial

I want to follow the structure of prod-test-dev.

In a git environment I would have a single project folder with 3 branches(prod-branch, test-branch, dev-branch).

How is this achieved with mercurial? As far as I understand you need to have 3(!) different projects. A project representing the production branch, another the dev etc.

This seems inefficient. Is there another way to achieve this? It can be that I have not really understood branches.

Update with pic showing the flow when I create this 3 branches in Mercurial:
[image]

Comment: What is stopping you from having 3 branches in Mercurial?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar this is the graph I get when I different branches to the same repo.

Comment: [Mercurial (named) branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches) are not like Git branches! You may be interested in 'bookmarks' (see `hg help bookmarks`), which are similar to Git bokmarks.

Comment: The main problem here is that you're continuing a branch from a different branch. You should update to the tip of a branch before working on it, this would give you parallel branches, you're just changing which branch to commit on for every commit, that's not really going to work. You need to find a good book or tutorial on Mercurial because there are many things that are incorrect about your workflow here, too many to cover in a single question and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic `prod-test-dev` flow would look like this:

Create new repository (or start with existing one). For start you have to create three named branches with following commands:

```
hg branch prod
hg commit -m"prod branch"
hg branch test
hg commit -m"test branch"
hg branch dev
hg commit -m"dev branch"
```

After you are done your repository will look like this:
[image: initialized repository with prod test and dev branches]

For development process you would update repository to `dev` branch and do some development there. After you have commited all changes to `dev` and are ready to release that code to testing do following `update` to `test` branch select `dev` branch in and perform `merge with local` (`dev` branch). Do the code fixing in `test` branch and when you are done merge back changes from `test` to `dev` branch (`update` to `dev`, select `test` branch - `merge with local`). Repeat cycle until you are ready for production. Then update to `prod` branch, select `test` and `merge with local` - and you will have your production code ready in `prod` branch.

After one development test production cycle your repository would look like this:

[image: Repository after dev - test - prod cycle]

You should also never close any of those three branches since they represent base for your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

As Lasse noted - just use Mercurial branches (named branches better) in **The Right Way (tm)**

Here **my** log of 2-branches repository with single-direction sync

[image: Log of two branches]